# What is the difference between do_compile[noexec] and empty function in bitbake recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

If I want to disable a particular build step, I can use either of these:

```
do_configure[noexec] = "1"
```

OR

```
do_configure() {
}
```

What is the difference between these alternatives? I have heard there can be raise conditions when using `noexec`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, there's normally 3 ways of removing a task:

1. `deltask` This completely removes the task and also it's dependencies. Thus, the tasks that might depend on the removed task won't get an automatic dependeny on the removed tasks dependencies. (A->B->C, and removing B doesn't create A->C). Thus, this should only be used if you know what you're doing.
2. Setting the task to empty `do_task() { : }`. This is the old way of disabling a task. The task will still be executed, but there's nothing in it do to. Thus, the execution overhead will remain.
3. `do_task[noexec]`, the newer way of disabling a task. Pretty similar to 2., but won't keep the execution overhead (as the task will never execute at all).

Comment: What happens to the dependent tasks when noexec is used? A->B, what happens to A when B is set to noexec?

Comment: There shouldn't be any differences between 2 and 3 when it comes to the dependent tasks. Thus , they will be executed nevertheless, and the complete dependency chain should be retained.